# What can be a function that take integers as input values,and give output as odd Numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, recreational-mathematics

I want a function that can get input as integers and give result as odd numbers.
for example  if x=1,y=1  then  (2,3)  (3,5)  (4,7)  (5,9)  (6,11)  expressing y in terms of x.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the points in the $xy$-plane, you'll see that they lie on a straight line:
$$
y=2x-1
.
$$

Comment: thanks ,it was simple,but didn't click my mind